# Need to add a listener to an element in a modal after it renders

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal window that pops up in response to clicking on a button. The modal has a controller assigned, and within that controller I have a list of IDs for elements that need the listeners assigned, however, at the time the controller initializes the modal has not yet rendered, and so the elements that need listeners don't exist yet. I'm trying to figure out how to assign the listener after the modal has displayed.

The call to create the modal looks like this:

```
ModalDialogFactory.showDialog(dialogOptions);
```

Then inside the factory:

```
        showDialog: function (modalOptions) {
            var modalConfig = {};
            angular.extend(modalConfig, modalDialogDefaults, modalOptions);
            modalInstance = $modal.open(modalConfig);
            modalInstance.opened.then(function() {
                // In here, I think
            })
            return modalInstance.result;
        }
```

Is there a way to take that modalInstance and access its controller functions after the modal displays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-init:

In modal html:

```
<span ng-init="vm.initialize()"></span>
<input ng-model="vm.model" type="text">
```

In modal controller:

```
vm.model = "new value";

function initialize() {
     $scope.$watch('vm.model', function(newVal, oldVal){
          console.log("value was changed to:"+newVal);
          vm.model.watch = newVal;
     });
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Meow3301...this is close I think, however, what I really need is to be able to call a single function in the controller *after* the modal opens, so the watch would have to be on the modal as a whole...some way to say 'when the modal is open and I have access to its elements, kick off this function'

Comment: @monkeyWithAMachinegun do you want to just access the modal controller functions before loading of modal? or you need to do something on the data/model before loading the modal?

Comment: actually it's the opposite - I need to access the controller functions *after* the modal fully renders.